# Facebook deauthorization callback is not called

Tags: facebook, api, callback, authorization

I have an FB app, when I enter as the deauthorization callback URL my development box address, the box is pinged with this request after app removal on FB:

```
POST /facebook/deauthorize HTTP/1.1
Host: bashman.org
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 261
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close

fb_sig_uninstall=1&fb_sig_locale=de_DE&fb_sig_in_new_facebook=1&fb_sig_time=1322732591.2685&fb_sig_added=0&fb_sig_user=1476224117&fb_sig_country=de&fb_sig_api_key=e39a74891fd234bb2575bab75e8f&fb_sig_app_id=32352348363&fb_sig=f6bbb27324aedf337e5f0059c4971
```

(The keys are fake here)

BUT! when I enter my production box URL in the deauthorization callback URL, the POST request is never made. Tested it with Tcpdump. No request on my production machine, why?

I checked with mtr the route from my production box to the IP address the request came from, all is OK, 0% packet lost.

The hostname port and path is correct, tested it 1k times, no firewall, IDS, or other systems blocking my ethernet slot.

1. Why is the Post callback not called? (How can I fix it?)
2. How I can debug this to determine what the issue is?

Comment: can you manually reach the production callback url? ie. in the browser?

Comment: Yes, trough curl on the same machine, trough curl / browser from other machines

Comment: what do you get back when using [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

Comment: thx, a redirection prevented the stuff from working, write a response, then I give you some points :)

Comment: no problem! facebook has a great array of tools for debugging :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the [facebook URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see if facebook's servers are able to reach your callback URL...
Viewing the information facebook IS able to retrieve might help you debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with NGINX and after hours of debugging I found this solution in NGINX [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html):

> Some browsers may complain about a certificate signed by a well-known
>   certificate authority, while other browsers may accept the certificate
>   without issues. This occurs because the issuing authority has signed
>   the server certificate using an intermediate certificate that is not
>   present in the certificate base of well-known trusted certificate
>   authorities which is distributed with a particular browser. In this
>   case the authority provides a bundle of chained certificates which
>   should be concatenated to the signed server certificate. The server
>   certificate must appear before the chained certificates in the
>   combined file:
>
> ```
> $ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt
> ```
>
> The resulting file should be used in the ssl_certificate directive:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen              443 ssl;
>     server_name         www.example.com;
>     ssl_certificate     www.example.com.chained.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
>     ... 
> }
> ```

In short, you just need to concatenate the certificate and the bundle and use the result as your ssl_certificate.

I am receiving the post requests from Facebook now.